# How to setup logging for cloud ml-engine during serving/inference

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

After loading a checkpoint; I have exported the model and then copied the `saved_model.pb` file and all the variables to GCS bucket.

During inference/serving, I get this error:

```
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION, details=\"Attempting to use uninitialized value shadow/LSTMLayers/stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/fw/basic_lstm_cell/bias\n\t [[Node: shadow/LSTMLayers/stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/fw/basic_lstm_cell/bias/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _output_shapes=[[2048]], _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0\"](shadow/LSTMLayers/stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/fw/basic_lstm_cell/bias)]]\")"
}
```

Please suggest me how to setup the logging at test/inference time in cloud ml-engine.

Comment: 1. What is your TF version. 2. What method did you use to export and save your model during training?  3. Are you using ```tf.global_variables_initializer()```?

Answer (score 1):

If you've set up a GCP project, you can write messages to the log using the [StackDriver Logging API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/). Then you can access log messages from the command line ([gcloud logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging)) or from the [developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com).